# How to collect the returned value of an awaited method in a variable in another method

Tags: c#, async-await

So I am trying to grab the source code from a url and here is my code:

```
public async Task<string> grabPageHtml(Uri pageUrl)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(pageUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "GET";
    WebResponse responseObject = await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
                                        request.BeginGetResponse,
                                        request.EndGetResponse, request);

    var responseStream = responseObject.GetResponseStream();

    var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    received = sr.ReadToEndAsync().Result;      
    return received;
}
```

The code works correctly and returns the sourcecode. The problem is assigning "received" to a string variable in another method.

Tried this:

```
string pageHtml = grabPageHtml(pageUrl)
```

but pageHtml outputs `System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1[System.String]` to the console instead of the source code.

Comment: You need to await it: `string pageHtml = await grabPageHtml(pageUrl);`

Comment: Hell no.. Don't mix async code with blocking code. It's a recipe for deadlock.  `received  = sr.ReadToEndAsync().Result` should be  `received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> pageHtml outputs System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[System.String]` to the
>   console instead of the source code.

That's because your method returns a `Task<string>`, not a `string`. You need to extract that string result somehow. It should be:

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    string pageHtml = await GrabPageHtmlAsync(pageUrl);
    Console.WriteLine(pageHtml);
}
```

As a side note, don't block on async code. Using `Task.Result` may lead to deadlocks. Also, using `HttpClient` would make your code a bit cleaner, removing the need to call `FromAsync`:

```
public Task<string> GrabPageHtmlAsync(Uri pageUrl)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    return httpClient.GetStringAsync(pageUrl);
}
```